# Design and analysis Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

How to find the minimum and maximum of subroutine median3(x,y,z) from a totally ordered set?

Comment: If you have totally ordered set, where is the catch? And what median3 does? (I can assume it finds median from 3 elements, but if these are ordered, then it is simply [min, median, max])

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What does "find the minimum and maximum of subroutine median3(x,y,z)" mean?  Do you mean to find the minimum of x,y,z?  (I'm not sure what median3 has to do with it.)  What are  your thoughts?  What approaches have you considered?  It seems pretty straightforward to find the minimum of three numbers, so I'm left wondering if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: given a list of n elements from a totally ordered set, it should return the minimum and maximum elements of the list as output using the median3(x,y,z) subroutine.